# Why does SQL Server Install Error 2019 Express fail with MSI instance already install

Tags: sql-server

I need help with SQL install. It keeps failing with error code below.

> Specified instance {A60B3D8E-5311-4BF1-AF7A-D1AC15F9152E} via transforms :InstID01.mst;:InstName01.mst is already installed. MSI INSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.

This was already asked in this forum but the solution doesn't work. Somehow there is an old remnants of the program on my system. I looked for the Microsoft clean up tool and it is no longer available. How else can I fix this? Is there a way I can remove this in the registry and if so which folder?

Thanks

Comment: I would try running the discovery report from the install media.  If it finds what you are trying to install....